# Blackberry and Ubuntu. As easy to connect?

Tags: 11.10, installation, software-recommendation, blackberry

How to connect Ubuntu to Blackberry? I'm tired, have no kits for handling or PLS-friendly software for managing smartphone. Above all BlackBerry. What software should I use to use as transmission modem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

[Smartphones and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3782/smartphones-and-ubuntu)

[Synchronize Blackberry Address book and Calendar with Evolution Directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12503/synchronize-blackberry-address-book-and-calendar-with-evolution-directly)

***Can you better define which feature (sync, modem, etc.) you really need?***

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for Desktop application to backup my blackberry contact, messages, blackberry messenger and media of devices.

I found some solutions like [Upubantu LinBerry](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/manage-your-blackberry-smartphone-with.html) but don't know how successful is this in your case but you can give it a shot.